# Akka http unsupported method exception

Tags: http, akka

I have a plain http route defined like so

```scala
delete {
           handleErrorsAndReport("delete_foo") {
              fooRepository.deleteFoo(fooId)
              complete(NoContent)
           }
}
```

I wanted to add some basic authentication to it so now it looks like

```scala
seal(
            authenticateBasic(
              realm = "Secure foo",
              scopeAuthenticator
            ) { scopes =>
              delete {
                handleErrorsAndReport("delete_foo") {
                  fooRepository.deleteFoo(fooId, scopes)
                  complete(NoContent)
                }
              }
            }
)
```

The full directive is

```scala
concat(
  get {
  // something else which is working
  },
  seal(
  // something else which is working
  ),
  seal(
              authenticateBasic(
                realm = "Secure foo",
                scopeAuthenticator
              ) { scopes =>
                delete {
                  handleErrorsAndReport("delete_foo") {
                    fooRepository.deleteFoo(fooId, scopes)
                    complete(NoContent)
                  }
                }
              }
  )
)
```

Now I am getting the following exception when I am trying to delete foos

```
 Request DELETE http://builder/foos/fooId failed with response code 405 due to request error. Response body: HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: PUT
```

What could be the issue? The way I've been consuming the API has not changed but I'm afraid that something has changed with the introduction of the `seal` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but this worked

```scala
concat(
  get {
  // something else which is working
  },
  seal(
              authenticateBasic(
                realm = "Secure foo",
                scopeAuthenticator
              ) { scopes =>
                concat(
                   delete {
                     handleErrorsAndReport("delete_foo") {
                       fooRepository.deleteFoo(fooId, scopes)
                       complete(NoContent)
                     },
                     put {//other authenticated endpoint}
                )
                }
              }
  )
)
```

In other words, I consolidated the two sealed directives which were before separate. Maybe it's related to [this](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/custom-route-rejection-end-up-in-405-method-not-allowed/3391)